# A better alternative for "second next"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase (in particular)  that exactly give the meaning of the page coming after the next page.

For instance, I am reading a book at page 203, but someone suggests me to read the page 205 which comes after 204 [the next page]. Here, what phrase or a word can be used for the page 205 after the next page.

I by my observation found the following phrase to define this: second next page. As we say second last (usually to mean before the last). But unfortunately, no google search results shows this phrase: neither [here](https://www.google.com/search?ei=Ptm-XOynMI-vyAPc17zgCA&q=second%20next%20page&oq=second%20next%20page&gs_l=psy-ab.3...452450.454826..455810...0.0..0.1030.3459.3-1j1j0j2j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0j0i22i30j33i21.Kx8mX-aX-g0) nor [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=second%20next%20meaning&oq=second%20next%20meaning&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).
 **The following picture might help what I am asking over here:**
[image: Picture of page numbers]
 The example sentence to consider:

> He suggested me to read a [page that comes after the next one].

Comment: I would not use "second last" in this context. It sounds like it should mean penultimate. "Page before last" is better.

Answer (score 4):

"The page after next" works.

Printed examples that refer to something two pages later:

> In the sidebar on the [page after next](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20page%20after%20next%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1-e), Bill Pearson, longtime comics writer, artist, and editor, reminisces about Reed Crandall and his art.
>
> The first model output in the [page after next](https://books.google.com/books?id=FP3-lKskU5YC&pg=PA497&lpg=PA497&dq=%22the%20page%20after%20next%22&source=bl&ots=dVNoC6hKOq&sig=ACfU3U3yEJNQezplyp26_WdQ-cc0B7f_MA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjM-8vrrebhAhXNmeAKHZbYCWwQ6AEwBnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22the%20page%20after%20next%22&f=false) has as the input Halo Active GRPs and prompted advertisement recall of Halo Active.
>
> A more detailed analysis of service retirement benefits begun this year is given on the [page after next](https://books.google.com/books?id=EKCy3vzSWdcC&pg=PA851&lpg=PA851&dq=%22the%20page%20after%20next%22&source=bl&ots=A4Yp5yT5p4&sig=ACfU3U2-05KuuIqcGCYltkZwvl91l3YnIg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjM-8vrrebhAhXNmeAKHZbYCWwQ6AEwCXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22the%20page%20after%20next%22&f=false).

Answer (score 3):

"The next page but one". This is certainly idiomatic and would be understood.

Comment: I recognize the idiom from reading. However, As an American speaker I have to think about this one pretty hard. It makes sense once I realize that "but" means "except," i.e. "next page except for one" that comes between.

Answer (score 2):

"Next but one"? Perhaps it might be an option local to the UK, or maybe even more regional than that, but it's certainly a phrase I'd naturally use. So for your example:

> He suggested to me to read the next but one page

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I would also use 'next but one' but would tend to form the sentence differently, more like "He suggested that I read the next but one page." I would also use "...next page but one." I'm afraid that I find the use of "to read" in your sentence quite clumsy.

Comment: Or "the page after next"